# How to prove $\overline{\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}}\cup\overline{\overline{A}\cup B}=A$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> $$\overline{\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}}\cup\overline{\overline{A}\cup B}=A$$

---

I have tried to prove this theorem but fail. Can you show me how to prove this statement?

Comment: Does the overbar mean closure (as in Ross' answer) or are you using it as set complement? I ask because 1) a question about closures should have a topology tag and 2) it is true if you are meaning complement. (In which case it can be proved by using DeMorgan's Law a bunch.

Comment: $\overline{A}$ denotes the complement of A?

Comment: Yes it denotes complement

Comment: use de Morgan's law

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

If $\overline{A}$ denotes the complement of A then

Note that: $\overline{A\cup B}=\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}$. Hence

$\overline{\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}}\cup\overline{\overline{A}\cup B}=(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap\overline{B})=A\cap(B\cup\overline{B})=A$

Answer (score 0):

This answer takes $\overline A$ to be the closure of $A$.  If it is the complement, the answer is incorrect.

It is not true unless $\overline B \subseteq \overline A$ and $\overline A = A$.  Take $A$ as $(0,1)$.  Then $\overline A=[0,1]$ and no $B$ can rescue the problem.  The left side is at least $\overline A$ and the right is at most $\overline A$

Comment: Hi friend. I think that $\overline{A}$ denotes the complement of $A$.

Comment: @J.rafa:  I think you are right.  It is easier to prove something that is true.  I have upvoted your answer.